# I get a NullReferenceException error when trying to use Tilemap.GetTile in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my code set up so that when the spacebar is clicked, the console prints out the current tile the player is on. However, I get this long error instead. Can someone please tell me how to fix this and/or why this is happening? This is the error:

> NullReferenceException UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTileAsset
>   (UnityEngine.Vector3Int position) <0x3886fc90 + 0x0005a> in
>   :0
>   UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile (UnityEngine.Vector3Int position)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/Tilemap/ScriptBindings/Tilemap.bindings.cs:113)
>   Player.Dig () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:56) Player.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:28)

My code is:

```
private void Dig()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Vector3Int playerPos = grid.WorldToCell(player.transform.position);
        Tilemap tilemap = new Tilemap();
        Debug.Log(tilemap.GetTile(playerPos));
    }
}
```

The code is in a method that runs in update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Tilemap`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.html) is a [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) and as every other `Component` should **never** be created using `new`! This is forbidden in Unity. A `Component` can only exist attached to a `GameObject` e.g. using [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) or by `Instantiate` a prefab with the components attached.

Best way however would be to [Create a Tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-CreatingTilemaps.html) already in the Editor and either use it directly or store it as prefab.

Then you can reference it in a field like e.g.

```
public Tilemap tilemap;
```